# JaversException COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND: JaVers bootstrap error - component of type 'org.javers.core.CommitIdGenerator' not found in container

Tags: javers

Using javers-core 3.9.7 I am facing this error when building javers. What exactly does this error message mean? javers doc doesn't have a description for it.

```
JaversBuilder.javers().withPackagesToScan("<omitted>").build();
```

JaversException COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND: JaVers bootstrap error - component of type 'org.javers.core.CommitIdGenerator' not found in container

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been reported here
https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/684
and
https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/682
and possibly fixed here
https://github.com/javers/javers/pull/683

A workaround suggested was to register the repository when building javers. For example:

```
JaversBuilder.javers().registerJaversRepository(new InMemoryRepository(CommitIdGenerator.RANDOM)).build();
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed is released in javers 3.10.1, see https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/682